# Issue with large input value in range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a piece of code and to test it i am calling function named "Comment" for n number of time with some input , where n = 2000000000 but seems to be giving error

Python version =  2.7.6

Piece of code:-

```
for i in range(2000000000):
   inp = getlis(input1)
   print inp,input2,Comment(inp,input2)
   inp = []
```

Output:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cha.py", line 103, in <module>
    for i in range(200000000):
MemoryError
```

Limit of range in python causing issue.

Comment: Are you going to use `i` in your loop?

Comment: leave it , i haven't pasted all the code . main Issue is with range(200..0) @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: I mentioned that because there's a better alternative if you're not using the `i` in your code anywhere.

Comment: lets assume i donot use variable "i", please provide your alternative answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
for i in xrange(2000000000):
```

> This function is very similar to range(), but returns an xrange object instead of a list. This is an opaque sequence type which yields the same values as the corresponding list, without actually storing them all simultaneously. The advantage of xrange() over range() is minimal (since xrange() still has to create the values when asked for them) except when a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine.